# DocuSign Update Document Tabs with data using SDK NodeJS

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to prefill document tabs with data using this:

```
    const tabSchema = {
              "textTabs": [
                {
                  "tabId":"f42260fe-ae95-4ef6-859d-290f2cdc6f4d",
                 
                  "value": "MARRIED",
                  
                  "documentId": documentId,
                 
                }
              ]
            };
    
            /*
    
            */
    
          
            //npm i @types/docusign-esign --save
            templateApi
              .updateTemplateDocumentTabs(
                accountID,
                templateID,
                documentId,
                tabSchema
              )
              .then((d) => {
                console.log(d);
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
              });
```

However it errors:

```
"errorCode":"INVALID_REQUEST_BODY","message":"The request body is missing or improperly formatted. No 
tabs specified."
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a URL like this one with correct documentID:

```
PUT [accountID]/templates/[TemplateID]/recipients/[DocumentId]/tabs
```

You should also include the `tabLabel` element for each tab. To find it - do a GET on the template that includes all the tabs.

Comment: I am using the npm docusign-esign wrapper library that does the put for me but I will try using the tabLabel

Comment: I changed the template to this:

Comment: `code` {
            "templateTabs":
                {
                 
                  "textTabs": [
                    {
                      "tabId":"f42260fe-ae95-4ef6-859d-290f2cdc6f4d",
                    
                      "value":"MARRIED",
                      
                      "documentId":"11543329",

                      "tabLabel":"Marital Status b305012d-5bed-46cc-8d57-d2074c605bbb"


                    
                    }
                  
                  ]
                }
        };

Comment: I receive the same error

Comment: Can you try to do this from the web app and record the API calls being called? that's how I did this, but maybe your situation is slightly different.  (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJYTDcc7cZw)

Comment: I was able to trap the logs.  Would you like to see them?

Comment: No, can you make the same API calls that are in the log yourself? that's what you are trying to do, no?

Comment: PUT https://demo.docusign.net:7802/restapi/v2.1/accounts/bcf6609f-c45c-4d01-9a2e-a2f9c1335f79/templates/9176935f-1e9f-412f-993d-5d8382506897/documents/11543329/tabs
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 2
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer [omitted]
Host: demo.docusign.net
{}

400 BadRequest
{"errorCode":"INVALID_REQUEST_BODY","message":"The request body is missing or improperly formatted. No tabs specified."}

Comment: is that from the web app logs? or when you do it from your code?

Comment: Making the call isn't the problem.  The problem is... how do I update the tabs in the template with information?

Comment: Web app logs after I make the call.

Comment: the web app allows you to update the information if you see on the right, you can update anything and everything about the tab. Now I think the confusion is you don't want to update the template, you want to update the envelope created from it, is that right?

Comment: The envelope has documents which have tabs that I want to populate with information

Comment: so you want to update an envelope, not a template?

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipienttabs/update/ that's the endpoint you need